# Split a list of numbers and loop through separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of numbers that refer to id's of a record, I need to loop through the list, and show the title and link of each resource. I currently have this:

```
- @otherresource = "1,2,3"

- @otherresource.split(",").each do |s|
  - Resource.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = 's'"]).each do |p|
    %li= link_to "#{ p.title }", "/resources/#{p.resourcetype}/#{p.title}"
```

But this only shows the first one from the list then stops. It doesn't loop through each number.

Comment: this is wrong: `"id = 's'"`

Comment: since you want all data, you should make one query in your controller and sort the objetcs in ruby. Spare db calls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should be responsible for fetching the resources from the database:

```
def action
  @otherresource = "1,2,3"
  ids = @otherresource.split ","
  @resources = Resource.where(id: ids) # fetch all resources at once
end
```

Then in your view:

```
- @resources.each do |p|
  %li= link_to "#{ p.title }", "/resources/#{p.resourcetype}/#{p.title}"
```

BTW, it might be a good idea to use an *association* for this kind of relation. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for details.

Comment: This is the best answer, IMHO :)

Comment: thank you, this worked with a few minor adjustments: `- Resource.where(id: @otherresource.split(',')).each do |res|
            %li= link_to "#{res.title}", "/resources/#{res.resourcetype}/#{res.title}"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd write this as follows, as it is more efficient to fetch multiple records in a single VS multiple database trips.

```
- @otherresource = '1,2,3'
- Resource.where(id: @otherresource.split(',')).each do |res|
  %li- link_to #{res.title}, "/resources/#{res.resourcetype}/#{res.title}"
```

The above query uses a single query as opposed to three queries in your example.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if `id` is equal your `s` variable. You are checking if `id` is equal the "s" character.
The correct condition should be:

```
 :conditions => ["id = '" + s + "'"]
```